# css - image stretched weirdly in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm currently testing out css for img tag. On chrome it look good but when I viewed it in firefox, the last image is stretched out. I'm not sure what's wrong. Below is my jsfiddle in which you can see the difference when you view it in Chrome and Firefox.

```
.thumbContainer img{
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
  object-fit: fill !important;
}
```

Comment: `display: -moz-box` and `display: box`? It's an 8/9 years old specification upgraded 2 times...update  your code to `flexbox` and everything will work as expected (you may even leave out `-moz` prefixes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, because you are using browser-specific CSS properties like [`-moz-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-box-flex) or `-webkit-box`, which are not officially supported. This can cause different behavior in different browsers, becauseit's up to the browser to decide how to display such elements, and for Firefox, the "correct" behavior is, to strech it, while for chrome its correct to fit in its parent. My general advice is: **Avoid styling with prefixed CSS** properties, unless it is absolutely necessary to enable standard CSS functionality in older browsers. Maybe there is another approach for your problem with [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).